# MySQL if exists update else create new

Tags: mysql

I have a vet table and a medical table with a 1 to many relationship, and the ID's are auto incremented.

```
CREATE TABLE vet(
      vetID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      vetPractice varchar(35),
      Address varchar(150),
      contactNumber varchar (15),
      PRIMARY KEY (VetID)
      );


CREATE TABLE medical(
      medicalID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      medication VARCHAR (200),
      PRIMARY KEY (medicalID),
      FOREIGN KEY (vetID) REFERENCES vet(vetID)
      );
```

Users can enter details of a vet, i want a query to determine;

- if the the vet details entered already exist, then update the foreign key in vetID(medical) with the entered vetID.
- else if the vet does not exist create a new vet and update the foreign key in vetID(medical) with the newly created vetID.

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: What SQL do you have so far for attempting this?

Comment: Your foreign key is incomplete. `medical` has no `vetID` field to reference the `vet` table with.

Comment: On a more relevant note, you'll need a decent search algorithm to check if the vet exists. Since the users are highly unlikely to know the vetID and very unlikely to type the exact same vetPractice name, such things as `ON DUPLICATE KEY` wouldn't be very helpful to you either. You could maybe try using `contactNumber` but plenty of offices have multiple phones; and different users may be aware of different numbers for the same practice.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do an upsert in MySql. I think that this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) can be helpful.

Example:

```
 INSERT INTO table (x,x,x) VALUES (x,x,x)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE x=x+x;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a "select" query to determine whether exists .

```
Select medicalID from medical where medication=?
```

This should be executed in a different query as the update , you need to use server language to see if the results brings back a result.Then using an "if" statement determine your routine. 
hope this helps.